# How to make sure data is entered in MongoDB after InsertOne/InsertMany Command?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using c# to insert a document in MongoDb, and want to make sure that data is inserted in Db. Is there a command  for that? I tried using 'Isacknowledged' command but seems like it is not supported.

Comment: I've removed the ASP.NET-Core tag from your question because the question isn't about ASP.NET Core. Anyway, if you don't get an exception, the data has been inserted.

Comment: When the data is not inserted (e.g. due to unique key violation) then you will get an error. If you have for example a network problem, then the command will hang till update was successfully done or get an error after timeout. Or do you use a ReplicaSet /Sharded Cluster and need to consider [Write Concern](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/write-concern/)?

Comment: `Isacknowledged` as I know mongo never had this command